# How to develop http handler which can handle multiple request

Tags: c#

here is my code ashx http handler which send something to client based on request.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string startQstring = context.Request.QueryString["start"];
    string nextQstring = context.Request.QueryString["next"];
    //null check
    if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(startQstring)) && 
    (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nextQstring)))
    {
        //convert string to int
        int start = Convert.ToInt32(startQstring);
        int next = Convert.ToInt32(nextQstring);

        //setting content type
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        DataClass data = new DataClass();
        //writing response
        context.Response.Write(data.GetAjaxContent(start, next));
    }
}
```

it is working but i am not sure that does it handle multiple request at a time like 1000 request serving at a time. if not then tell me best way to write code in such way which can handle multiple request at the same time in efficient way. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good, but if your DataClass instance writes to any shared state, there might be a problem.

Comment: can't u give small code example which shows whatever u said here just to make any http handler capable of handling multiple request. thanks

Comment: can u plzz tell me what u r trying to mean share state....like session variable or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Everything will depend on the implementation of the `GetAjaxContent` method on your `DataClass`. If this method doesn't rely on some shared state and it is thread safe your code should be able to handle multiple clients concurrently. Because you are using only local variables (except the `GetAjaxContent` method for which we cannot know what it does) your code is thread safe.

Comment: can't u give small code example which shows whatever u said here just to make any http handler capable of handling multiple request. thanks

Comment: @user750398, thread safety is a vast topic. Basically you must ensure that the `DataClass` that you are using doesn't depend on static members or it tries to access some shared resource (such as a file) in which case you will need to synchronize the access to this shared resource using a proper synchronization technique (which will depend on the shared resource your class is using). I can provide you an example that is guaranteed to always work and this is to hardcode the value `context.Response.Write("some value");`. You will need to provide more details about your DataClass and what it does.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, you don't understand. Look at user750398's profile, look at the previous questions he has posted, look at what he is asking in the comments, and see what happened to most of his questions. Then, perhaps it will all make sense.